# Directory Structure for Slim/Vue.js project

Tags: php, vuejs2, slim

I am developing an application using Slim backend and vue.js frontend. But finding it difficult to map the Ajax calls from vue.js resource to RESTful API of slim. My current directory structure is like this:

```
|-silmapp
  |- composer.json
  |- package.json
  |- app
     |- //php RESTful APIs
  |- vendor
     |- // all dependent files for SLIM and php
  |- index.php  //main program
```

Many sites discuss many different directory structures, including `backend` and `frontend` directory structures but I am not able to link. Kindly suggest a directory structure.

Comment: show detail message please，what's wrong? 404 or other wrong?what's your nginx configure?

Comment: I am using Apache 2 but don't have root privilege. My public-html folder is mapped by the administrator. "index.php" works fine without any frontend js framework like vuejs. That is, I am able to get the desired json file from the backend. But to display it beautifully and add action, I need vuejs with webpack in frontend. This is my problem. Some are using `public` folder but I don't have access to http.conf file so I can't use it.

Comment: i still confuse，could you give me example?you can not use vue.js?404 of  vue.js?

Comment: what's meaning of "i am not able to link"

Comment: My URL is [here](http://www.amrita.ac.in/rsreekumar/slimapp/students) where `students` refer to `slimapp\app\routes\students.php`. `index.php` invokes this file for route `/students`. As you can click and see the output is an array of plain json objects. Now I need to beautify them. I am not sure where to put my front-end javascript files like `index.html` and the corresponding `main.js`, `bundle.js` files.

Comment: "i am not able to link" means how to connect the front-end events with back-end routers. And which is the best way to place front-end js and html files and backend php files.